# volumetric flow rate due to Bernoulli's principle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

for calculating the volumetric flow rate of a liquid coming out of a tube, I know that If the pipe is too short, the Hagen–Poiseuille equation may result in unphysically high flow rates; the flow is bounded by Bernoulli's principle

So, what exactly is the Volumetric Flow rate due to Bernoulli's principle ( the formula )?

Comment: Google 'orifice equation ' or 'flow through an orifice'. The practical formulation usually adds a coefficient of discharge that accounts for the specific orifice geometry and vena contracta

Answer (score 1):

Find the velocity using bernoulli's equation

Pressure + G.P.E per unit volume + K.E per unit volume = constant

and apply the equation for flow rate.

Flow rate = Area x Velocity

Comment: Sorry what is G.P.E per unit volume + K.E per unit volume?

Comment: Gravitational potential energy and Kinetic energy.

Comment: So you mean if I change the cross section I can't have the same velocity ? 
But my question is the formula that gives me the relation between the volumetric flow rate and pressure and Area and Velocity

Comment: It is the Bernoulli's equation that I have written in words. :)

Comment: oh u need the flow rate.. Let me edit my answer

Comment: I want to change the Area without velocity being changed, is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28839/discussion-between-david-2000-and-slhulk).

Answer (score 1):

The equation you are looking for is [derived on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orifice_plate#Theory).